# Problem with content unpublish in Tridion 2013 SP1 HR1

Tags: tridion

We are having problems with unpublishing the content of any Tridion publication. When we try to unpublish any content, these unpublished elements do not disappear from the application of the front and remain in the file system. After unpublishing the content, we have verified the following actions:

- In the Tridion publishing queue, the content has been successfully unpublished, giving Success in the queue.
- It is verified that the icon next to the element that indicates if an element is published, also disappears.
- In the "Where used" tab, it does not appear that the item is published in any target.
- Finally, check that in the Broker the unpublished content has also disappeared.

As we have commented previously, the problem of unpublication occurs with any publication of Tridion, therefore, we discard the problem of advertising or the application in particular. The permissions have also been revised in the front applications are correct.

On the other hand, when we publish any content, it works correctly, updating this published element with the content and the correct date of the publication in the front of the application.

Thanks a lot for you help!!

Andres.

Comment: The most likely explanation is that the Deployer is not configured correctly. Have you checked the cd_storage_conf.xml to see where the deployer is trying to place / remove the files? Is that the location that contains the files that aren't being removed? Is it configured to use the file system at all?